# How to structure re-used code between modules

Tags: python, module

I'm pretty new to Python and, in writing an app, have ended up with a structure that's a bit of a mess. The example below should illustrate what I'm trying to do. The issue is that I can't call the login method from common.py because it is only defined in website1.py or website2.py.

Module common.py

```
class Browser():

    def load_page():
        Login.login()
```

Module website1.py
    import common.py

```
class Login:
    @staticmethod        
    def login():
        #code to login to this website 1
```

Module website2.py
    import common.py

```
@staticmethod
class Login:
    def login():
        #code to login to website 2
```

Any thoughts on how to restructure this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why static methods? You could just do `def login` at the global level.

Second of all, you could pass a class reference to the `Browser` class. (or a module reference if you take my first suggestion)

```
class Browser(object):
    def __init__(self, loginCls):
        self.loginCls = loginCls

    def login_page(self):
        self.loginCls.login()
```